# does windows install correct drivers when i connect my samsung mobile?

Tags: windows-7, networking

when i connect my galaxy j5 to pc and enable usb tethering it install drivers and everything works fine but windows install *usb composite device* instead of *samsung mobile usb composite device*  and i do not know it until yesterday...
is that wrong or lead to internet sharing not work good ?
because i downloaded very important files with this method...
im using windows 7 32-bit

Comment: If it worked then you're probably fine.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 (now very old) should install the proper drivers. Windows 10 does install the proper drivers. Our clients (and me) use different phones, all Windows 10 now and drivers install properly